# Flutter - Dropdown value

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I need use a string as a value in the flutter dropdown. But returns

> Another exception was thrown:
>   'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   609 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
>   items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) => item.value == value).length
>   == 1': is not true.

Full log [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvI2c.png).

The code is

```
items: dataMaker.map((item) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            child: new Text(item['fabricante'],
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                            value: item['fabricante'], //FAIL
                          );
                        }).toList(),
```

So my question in: How can i use a string as item value? Another solution is get the text of dropdown but i don´t know how.

**--SOLUTION--**

With this code I can find all the elements in the dataMaker list that have the same text as the drop-down menu.

```
 var test =dataMaker.firstWhere((fabricante) => fabricante["id"].toString() == dropdownSelectionMaker);              
 dataModelo = dataMaker.where((modelo) => modelo["fabricante"] == test["fabricante"]).toList();
```

Comment: Check my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/56049765/2315974. Is the same problem as you have.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure how the library does the comparison but I found that though the value was in he list it still returned the error, so I had to do  some manual comparison. NOTE: `BuildingType` is just a custom data type.
Here's the magical line for my case: 
`value: selectedType == null ? selectedType : buildingTypes.where( (i) => i.name == selectedType.name).first as BuildingType,`

```
return DropdownButton<T>(
  hint: Text("Select Building type"),
  value: selectedType == null ? selectedType : buildingTypes.where( (i) => i.name == selectedType.name).first as BuildingType,
  onChanged: handleBuildingTypeChange,
  items: abcList.map((T value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<T>(
      value: value,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Text(
            value.name,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
);
```

Comment: This answer should be checked. 
Thanks @Denn

Answer (score 4):

The `DropdownButton` widget has the following assertion

```
assert(items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1,
                "There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: "
                '$value. \n'
                'Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected '
                'with the same value',
              )
```

In this assertion the following part fails and returns empty list

```
items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              })
```

In my case i was using an object of a class that contained several other properties
I override  the `== operator` for that class and it worked!
Following is an example of operator overriding

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int id;

  Person(this.name, this.id);

  bool operator ==(o) => o is Person && o.name == name && o.id == id;
}
```

Comment: Another option is to use the great https://pub.dev/packages/freezed library instead of manually overriding

Answer (score 2):

try this hope its works for you :

```
 new DropdownButton(
                            value: _current,
    items: dataMaker.map((item) {
                              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                child: new Text(item.fabricante,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                value: item.fabricante, //FAIL
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            onChanged: (selected) => setState(() {
      _current = selected;
    });
```

Comment: Exception occurred caused by default value `_current`.
If you not initialize value when before building the dropdown button, dropdown builder can't be found init value.

Answer (score 0):

Here works fine,

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: bloc.selecionado$,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasData){
      return DropdownButton(
        items: bloc.listAtletas.value.map( (v){
          return DropdownMenuItem<AtletasObj>(
            child: Text("${v.nome}"),
            value: v,
          );
        }).toList(),
        value: bloc.selecionado.value,
        isDense: true,
        onChanged:(v){bloc.changeAtletaSelecionado(v);                                                                                                              bloc.changeObjetoSelecionadoFunction(v);},
      );
      }
      return Container(height: 0.0, width: 0.0,);
    }
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

for me i just initialize `selectedValue` with first element in the list as you see:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      String selectedValue = list.first;

       ....
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this method,
Thats how i use sometimes.

Code may contain some problem bcz i have created it in normal TextEditor.

```
items: (){
    List<Widget> data = List<Widget>();
    for(int i=0;i<dataMaker.length;i++){
        data.add(
            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                child: Text(item['fabricante'],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                value: item['fabricante'],
            );
        );
    }
    return data;
}
```